# Show that $\phi$ is continuous on $E$.

Tags: lebesgue-measure

Let $f:X \to C$ be measurable, $||f||_{\infty} > 0$, and let $\phi(p)= \int_X|f|^pd\mu$, and let
$$E=\{p \in (0,\infty): \phi(p) < \infty\}$$
I would like to show that $\phi$ is continuous on $E$. I am really stuck on this. Any helps would be appreciated!

Comment: If $p_n \to p$ then by continuity of $x \to a^x$ ,we have $|f|^{p_n} \to |f|^p$ pointwise a.s. when $|f| < \infty$. Now push DCT through.